# Printing inside a class (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a trouble in my `Visual Studio` `C++ Project`.
At the moment in my `main.cpp` I can print using:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

I have tried to print inside a different file `Party.cpp`
using the same methods in the `main.cpp`, but I have noticed that including `<iostream>` gives me errors like :

> Error 4   error C2059: syntax error : ')'

in `tmmintrin.h` line `90`.
I have no idea what is `tmmintrin.h` , it is not on my project and my project can not be compiled because of that reason.
If anyone have faced this problem / know how to solve I would like to get helped.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `;` in one of your headers

Comment: In the Output tab is this the first error listed? And yes I mean output tab and not the errors list.

Comment: This is far from a complete description of your problem and is very likely due to an error in one of your files. This has almost certainly nothing to do with printing.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved it was

```
#include "Party.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
```

and i changed the order to

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Party.h"
```

Comment: If that works it would suggest that "Party.h" does *not* contain proper include guards or is itself not including something it needs. You should fix that. The transformation you show *should not* make any difference for any well behaved headers. (And btw; please stop using `using namespace std;`)